# DBlink PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Прошу помочь так как немного не могу сам разобрать, только начал изучать.
Имеется задача заполнять таблицу из другой базы данных.

```
INSERT INTO sovtreposrt (comment, cout, sort) values 
('Результат', 'Количество','2')
 from  dblink('host=**** port=***user=***password=***dbname=Cx_Work',
' SELECT 'Отменено в рамках проверки федерального закона'  as "Результаты", count("State") as "Количество"' t (comment VARCHAR(50), count VARCHAR(50), sort int4)
WHERE  "StartTime" >= current_date 
and "IDCampaign" in (5030490429,5107806228,5279099748,5100578818,5107806231,5279606886) 
and "State" = 3), "S_CampaignsCalls"
```

Выводит ошибку:

> [Err] ОШИБКА:  ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "from")
>   LINE 1: ...out, sort) values ('Результат', 'Количество','2') from  dbli...

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял исходный запрос...
Вы добавляете в таблицу `sovtreposrt` БД `Cx_Work` результат выборки из таблицы `S_CampaignsCalls`, которая находится в БД `Cx_Statis`.

Согласно документации (https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/contrib-dblink-function), думаю, должно работать что-то типа

```
INSERT INTO sovtreposrt (comment, count, sort) 
SELECT * FROM dblink('host=**** port=***user=***password=***dbname=Cx_Statis',
  'SELECT ''Удачные звонки'', COUNT("State"), 1 FROM "S_CampaignsCalls" WHERE "StartTime" >= current_date AND "IDCampaign" IN (5030490429,5107806228,5279099748,5100578818,5107806231,5279606886) AND "State" = 3')
  AS t(comment VARCHAR(50), count VARCHAR(50), sort int4)
```

Обратите внимание на следующие моменты:

- Когда вы выполняете запрос, вы должны находиться в БД `Cx_Work` и подключаться через `dbblink` к БД `Cx_Statis`.
- Количество и тип выбираемых из другой БД значений должны совпадать с количеством и типом добавляемых.
- Если в таблице, в которую вы добавляете запись имеется поле, объявленное как NOT NULL и для него не предусмотрено значение по умолчанию, вы должны упомянуть его в списке полей для заполнения и, соответственно, указать (или выбрать) для него значение.
- Константные значения в одинарных кавычках надо экранировать, поскольку сам запрос так же в кавычках.
- Количество и тип выбираемых значений в подзапросе должно совпадать с количеством, порядком и типом в `t (comment VARCHAR(50), count VARCHAR(50), sort int4)`
- Насколько я в курсе, есть либо `INSERT INTO ... (...) VALUES (...)`, либо `INSERT INTO ... (...) SELECT ... FROM ...`

Если вы новичок, то делайте сложные запросы по частям. То есть, сначала добейтесь нормальной выборки через `dblink`. Всё-таки неплохо посмотреть что вы будете добавлять. Убедитесь, что количество и тип значений такие же как в таблице, куда собираетесь добавлять. Потом дописывайте в начале (первой строкой) `INSERT INTO sovtreposrt (comment, cout, sort) values`.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88634/discussion-on-answer-by-gooamoko-dblink-postgresql).